# Align the text properly inside circle

Tags: html, css

visit this [link1](http://test.collagekingapp.com/chhota-bheem-jaggu-keychain.html) search for 10% using Ctrl + F

visit this [link2](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/chhota-bheem-jaggu-keychain.html) search for 50% using Ctrl + F

In link 1, "10% OFF" is displaying in cirlce, but in the second one its not displaying properly. Any ideas to get it to work?

code :

```
.quick .you_savee{

border : 1px solid #ccc;
border:radius : 37px;
color : green;

left:151px;
position:relative ! important;
top:-100px;

}
```

Comment: You should demonstrate the issues with code **in the question** not just links. In fact it's required.

Comment: In any case there are dozens of questions about text in circles you could have checked before posting here. At least one of those is bound to have your answer, so this is obviously a duplicate.

Comment: @Paulie_D i will post code from next time and i searched related type of problems, but i did't got. thanks for your hints.

Comment: Next time isn't good enough. This question is likely to attract negative attention if it isn't improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use display:block; on after element.

```
 .Quick .you_save_price::after {
    content: "OFF";
    display: block;
  }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctkn2.png